# Getting error "The package appears to be corrupt" in Fabric Beta on Android 6

Tags: android, google-fabric, fabric-beta

All my beta testers with Android 6 get this error when installing my app from Beta:

> App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt

No problems for users with Android 7+. The APK can be dirrectly installed on all devices, including those with error in Beta. The problem appeared a few days ago, configuration of project did not change.

All my users uses latest 1.7.0 Beta app. Project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Any help?

UPD.
I removed android:extractNativeLibs="false" from AndroidManifest.xml and now it works.

Comment: Todd from Fabric. Are you using ABI splits in your app? This could cause this type of issue. Let me know! :)

Comment: No, I use native code without ABI splits. I am also using android:extractNativeLibs="false" in manifest, can this cause this problem?

Comment: Thanks Rzhik. Can you test a distribution with that change to see if it clears things up? We haven't seen other reports of this issue, so it is likely project specific. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've found the problem, it was in android:extractNativeLibs="false" row in my manifest file. I removed it and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to downgrade gradle from version 3.0.0 (introduced with Android Studio 3) to 2.3.3 (previous version).
I made this by replacing this line in the project .gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

With:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

After a clen and build i was able to upload my app to Beta and install it with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the apk first by :-1 Build > Build apk(s)
This is because of security issue. if any non-developer want your APK, so its easily to get it from your folder. so now it does not happen only developer will able to create sharable APK.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239041/beta-by-crashlytics-package-appears-to-be-corrupted/47062780#47062780)

Since Android Studio 3.0, I have the exact same problem if I try to upload an apk via the user interface.

For now, you will have to use the command line in order to upload an apk, as the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html#distribution-with-gradle) says.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug
```

I hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem removing

```
android:extractNativeLibs="false"
```

from the `AndroidManifest`, until Fabric fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot i find a solution:

Go to Build-> Build Apk(s).

After create apk you will show dialog as below.

Click on locate and install it into your phone

Enjoy