# Getting error "The package appears to be corrupt" while installing apk file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having a weird problem.I got this error after I updated Android Studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0..The problem is when I try to install apk file it says

App not installed.
The package appears to be corrupt.

I have tried generating apk in both debug and release version and tried to install but whenever I install apk it show the same message..

When I run the android project from android studio it is working.
May be the gradle problem but couldn't fix it.
Please help

Comment: answer few things, 
01. What is your package name?
02. Is that app already installed in your device?
03. Was this working before upgrading your studio?
04. Did you checked your device settings, "Install from external sources".

Comment: 1) Are you using the emulator?
2)is there any other app with the same package name in your device?

Comment: @Shekhar.. 01. My package name is similar before updating android studio.. 02. I tried both ways.. keeping old version app in device as well as uninstalling old app.. 03.. Yes it was working before updating android studio.. 04. Yes, it is already checked..

Comment: @Ronak Thakkar.. 1)I am using emulator as well as physical device. one at a time.. 2) No there aren't any other app with the same package..

Comment: and in both emulator and physical device you get the same error?

Comment: Yes...When I run the project from android studio is works well in both device.. and when I install apk file manully I am facing that problem

Comment: try disabling the Instant Run, Clean the build, make signed apk again, then it will work.

Comment: The .apk file could be improperly signed or it could be corrupt.
So clean and rebuild the project and make new apk. Hope this will work

Comment: Have you updated gradle  plugin to 3 ?

Comment: try disabling the Instant Run, Clean the build, make signed apk again, then it will work. 
Did you tried?

Comment: It was running fine in gradle 3.0.0 but suddenly after android studio update it stopped working.. Now I am using gradle 2.3.3 and working fine..

Comment: Having the same problem. Installation works fine through Android Studio but not when manually installing apk. Rollbacking gradle to 2.3.3 from 3.0.0 made it work again

Comment: @user3678528 in main gradle right?

Comment: on Android Oreo you get a message that "App is not installed", it is the same issue. The accepted answer solves it.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

After searching a lot I found a solution:

Go to Build-> Build Apk(s).

After creating apk you will see a dialog as below.

[image]

Click on locate and install it in your phone

Enjoy

Comment: phew! thanks. I am confused why it doesnt work without Build Apk(s).

Comment: @usman :- security issue. if any non-developer want your APKso its easily got from your folder. so now it does not happen only developer will able to create share APK.

Comment: ThankS!! If you notice, the APK generated from this process is almost 3 times the size of an APK generated by a regular Run/Build.

Comment: This actually works for me. But android studio need to put a check on that. it's a serious issue

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. It will not show following message any more.
'App not installed. The package to be corrupt'. Previously, I was just copying apk from build folder and it doesn't work.

Comment: This environment is getting worse every day... It could be better if they add useful features instead of shit like that...

Comment: How to generate release verison? I am having the same problem with release verison...

Comment: this solution for  build version (debug) but what about release ? same problem occurring with release version :(

Comment: I believe that installing an unsigned relesae version of an APK doesn't work unless you take specific steps to allow this. You're supposed to sign the release APKs. There are various resources out there explaining how to do it, but it's pretty disjoint information.

Comment: i have try below solution but not work for me. 1) reset catch & rebuild project 2) upgrading gradle class path version 3) down grading target SDK version 29 to 28

Answer (score 9):

As I got this case at my own and the answers here didn't help me, my situation was because of I downgraded the `targetSdkVersion` in gradle app module file from **24** to **22** for some reason, and apparently the apk doesn't accept another one with downgraded `targetSdkVersion` to be installed over it.

So, once I changed it back to **24** the error disappeared and app installed correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that was it for me too. I had only looked at the Manifest, but build.gradle seems to override targetSdkVersion of manifest.

Comment: @FrankKrumnow great that i could help in solving your issue, best luck.

Answer (score 4):

When you are releasing signed apk , please make sure you tick both **v1** and **v2** in **signature versions**

See below screenshot for more info 
[image: Signed APK generation]

Answer (score 3):

This is weird. I don't know why this was happening with me while generating signed apk but below steps worked for me.

1. Go to file and select invalidate caches/restarts
2. After that go to build select clean project
3. And then select Rebuild project

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case; If you receive this error while updating your application, It may be because of the target SDK version. In such case you will receive this error on logs;

`"Package com.android.myapp new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 23 does"`

This is because your previous aplication was build with a higher version of sdk. If your new app was build with 22 and your installed application was build with 23, you will get `The package appears to be corrupt` error on update.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the target phone had the app already installed, but in a "disabled" state.  So the user thought it was already uninstalled, but it wasn't.  I went to the main app list, clicked on the "disabled" app, uninstalled it, and then the APK would go on.

Answer (score 1):

Running a direct build APK will work. But make sure you uninstall any previously installed package of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case by making build, from Build> Build apks,  it worked.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer is working for me.

As the error message is package corrupt , I will have to run

1. `adb uninstall <package name>`
2. Run app again / use adb install

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a problem with my module level **build.gradle** file.
I somehow had removed the line

```
compileSdkVersion 32
```

from the file.
This didn't prompt any issue during the build time but only when installing which is where "The package appears to be corrupted" line occurred.
Adding the line back solved my issue.

Please re-check your build.gradle and AndroidManifest for any anamolies since the corrupt message is very ambiguous and hard to debug the exact cause for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By version number, I mean the versionCode in the app/build.gradle file

The Scenario:
I have an APK installed. Its version number is 152430.

I was trying to install a new APK (by downloading the new APK file) and updating the existing app. The New APK was having version number : 152427

Since the New APK was having version number less than the already installed APK, it was throwing this error.

The solution:
The version number needs to be higher than the installed APK version.