# "The package appears to be corrupt" while installing APK on Galaxy S7

Tags: android, installation, apk, samsung-mobile, diawi

I made an Android project on Android Studio. When I ran it on test Android device which was plugged to my system using a USB cable, it ran successfully.

However, then I generated the APK and uploaded in [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) website. When I tried to install this APK, I got following error:

> App not installed.
>
> The package appears to be corrupt.

[image]

APK file however is not corrupt at all since when I installed it manually after copying it from `build` folder, it was successfully installed on the Galaxy S7.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: is the APK in Diawi is Signed APK  ?

Comment: No it is unsigned

Comment: Android Studio 3.0. `android:testOnly="true"` https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Comment: Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47136969/7894033)..
I got the same error and Solved using that Link..

Comment: @greenapps your link was pretty useful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, **I signed APK with V2 signature** and it showed this error message. **I tried signing the app only using V1 scheme and it worked.**

As official docs say, if you have problem building APK using V2 scheme, you can skip and sign only using V1.

Answer (score 1):

**In Android Version May 25th-2019 I faced similar issue :**

Build -> Build Apk(s) and then locate apk from build -> output -> apk -> debug

**Solve my issue.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try avoiding put the names: com.example, com.android, etcc in your package, then Build>Rebuild and/or BuildGenerate signed APK and follow the steps. I hope help you!

Comment: my package name does not uses these names.. it is very different from these.

Comment: Try to sign your apk before uploading it to Diawi, that works for me :/

Comment: requirement is that i need to upload debug apk.

Comment: You can sign the debug apk too