# Release build is corrupted when updating support gradle plugins as 28.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

My release build was corrupted when I using android support version as `28.0.0-alpha`. But release build working fine with `support version 27.1.1`.

**Additional Info :** version `name` and `code` is missed on release build with `support version 28.0.0-alpha`

so How to resolve it?

Comment: what does it mean "corrupted" ?

Comment: I unable to install apk on device because version name and code was missed in apk. whwn I try to install the release build in app ,it's shows message `app not installed,apk was corrupted`

Comment: @RajasekaranM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973058/getting-error-the-package-appears-to-be-corrupt-while-installing-apk-file

Comment: I checked it. is apk is signed when I generate apk  with `Build apk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FYI**

**alpha** is a version of a piece of software that is made available for testing.

> [**`28.0.0-alpha1`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions?authuser=1#28-0-0-alpha1) is a ***pre-release*** version to support the Android P developer preview. Its API surface is subject to change, and it does
>   not necessarily include features or bug fixes from the latest stable
>   versions of Support Library.

You should use stable version (**`27.1.1`**) for **Release** build.

Comment: yes I agree,I like to know the reason for apk corruption

Comment: @RajasekaranM May be any system level issue happen.

Comment: @RajasekaranM You need to build the apk first by `Build > Build apk(s)`

Comment: signed apk not working for me ,debug apk's are working fine

Comment: @RajasekaranM Solved this yet?