# Can anyone check my manifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am a programmer newbie. I want to build my own app. I have builded the APK to test it on my LG G6. But there's an error message "there was a problem parsing the package" when installing. I read that this could be caused by a corrupted Manifest. I haven't found a problem there. But I am just a beginner, so it'd be great if you could check it out and maybe you can tell me the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="e.jonathan.kirchenappalpha">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Kirchgemeinde Königshain BETA"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Info"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".veranstaltungen"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".monat_1"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".monat_2"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".monat_3"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".feedback" />
        <activity android:name=".Gemeindekreise"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Granle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "e.jonathan.kirchenappalpha"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
}
```

Comment: can add your app gradle ? because may be issue in it

Comment: Does it work on emulators? How are you building the APK (through gradle command or IDE)?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue but it's not  happened because of  manifest. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186569/release-build-is-corrupted-when-updating-support-gradle-plugins-as-28-0-0-alpha1

Comment: Grandle Code added

Comment: It worked on my emulators. Only my phsical smartphone makes these problems.

Comment: Do you generate a Signed APK ?

Comment: No I selected Build APK(s)

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: doesn't work but I hoenestly don know how to do this properly

Comment: Cool. Will help with you.

Comment: Or I could try it on another physical device

Comment: Have you authorised [installation from unknown sources](https://drfone.wondershare.com/android-issue/problem-parsing-the-package.html) on your test device?

Comment: Yeah I have checked this and it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the app on a physical device, Connect your phone & switch on Developer options on your phone (tap 7 times on Build Number), [setup ADB](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) , and `Run > Run App` (Shift + F10)

Although, for generating an APK, head over to `Build > Generate Signed APK`. You can find some help [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).