# How do I check if the signing of an app is correct?

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, keystore

I'm developing some changes for an app. It worked properly and compile fine before I configured a VPN (I think this may be related to the problem). Since that the aplication compiles fine but I can't update from previous versions to the new one (let's say from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1), an error message says "The package appears to be corrupt". The version number and code are updated.
[I've found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973058/getting-error-the-package-appears-to-be-corrupt-while-installing-apk-file), but it doesn't fix my problem: I've compiled in release and debbug.

It's documentated that the problem is related with [the signing of an app in Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=windows) because I can install the apk from scracth without updating, I've loaded the keystore again, check the path %AppLocalData%, configure again the path manually... nothing. Besides, the 'debbug.keystore' file doesn't open when the app is compiled, nevertheless it's open when I use the command in the document to load it again. I don't know if it should open, just saying. The key file is the same, nothing else changed.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you try to update the version? When you remove the VPN configurtion, does it work well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made everything above again and it worked, not sure what was wrong. For those of you that may have a similar problem that's what I tried:

- Check your keystore  (it must be the same for different compilations) and store in a safe place as Cheesebaron says.
- Check you have well configured [the path for your keystore](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=windows).
- You may have a wrong enviroment variable if the step above fails (i.e. %AppLocalData% pointing to other location).
- Check your version number. The number for a version must be higher than previous versions, you may use YYMMddXX (XX for differnet compilations in the same day)
- If you altern to compile in release/debug, make sure your code doesn't affect the path to the keystore

Answer (score 1):

The debug.keystore is as the name suggests, only for debugging. It will differ between different machines you install Visual Studio.

Make your own keystore and save it somewhere secure. Especially if you plan to release the App in Play Store. If you misplace it, you will have a bunch of issues.

Creating your own keystore will also ensure the same and correct signature every time, and you can configure your project to use your own keystore instead of the debug.keystore that Xamarin.Android defaults to.