# when i try to install android application, "app not installed" and stopped. how to fix it

Tags: android, installation, operating-system, version

When we try to install our android application, "app not installed" error came and stopped. how to fix this issue and we want to install our application and have to debug my app in android studio. My mobile having android 11 version, and android studio updated with chipmunk version.

Comment: You are going to have to supply us, and yourself, with may more information. Have you collected the logs? Watched the install via ADB? Android will tell you exactly why the installed failed, which you need to know before you can proceed. This is unanswerable as is.

Answer (score 2):

If you generate an apk and it doesn't even install (because of the message you get) check if you have a previous version installed. If so you can either:

1. Uninstall de previous version and install the new one
2. Change the version code in Manifest, it has to be greater to the current one. You should also check (if you sign the apk) that the key is the same, [I had a similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958945/how-do-i-check-if-the-signing-of-an-app-is-correct/70986776#70986776)

Other causes could be:

- Check that the minSdk is equal or lower than 30 (Android 11) to garantee your device is compatible
- How big is your app? Maybe you don't have enough space in your device
- Maybe your .apk file is just corrupted, try to compile it again

Comment: After uninstalled only i have tried to install the build. I have checked the version , device and build are in same version which i try  to install.  My device having lot of space too , hence its not have storage problem. i am changing the manifest declarations and i am still trying.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio,
Build option-> Build Bundle(s) -> Build Bundle's / Build APK's    -> Build APK's

I have installed that build APK, finally installed